# How can you render a build number / hash with a git-deployed Windows Azure Website?

Tags: git, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I've got a website on azure that I deploy via git (kudu). I'd like to be able to show the git hash of the current deployment in the footer - is this possible?

I imagine what I'm looking for is some way to hook into kudu to edit a CS file after the git pull but before the compile - is this possible on WAWS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach using custom deployment scripts can probably work. Please see some related discussion on [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1336). During deployment, Kudu creates an `%home%\site\deployments\active` file which contains the commit ID, so you could just read that at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

Found a way: You can hook into kudu by following the instructions at https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-hooks

To get the git hash into a file I added

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD > "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\version.txt"
```

to the post deploy area of the cmd file. If i'd wanted to do something to a CS file I could have done so before the compile, it's quite obvious what the deploy script that's generated by azure cli is trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

In our solution (ASP.NET MVC) we have added one additional project that is always built as the first project. This project references the nuget package 'GitSharp' which is a managed .NET Git client library. The output of the additional project is a command line tool which we called VersionNumberGenerator.exe.

On the post-build event of this additional project we execute VersionNumberGenerator.exe. This produces a file AssemblyInfoShared.cs which also includes the source code for a class containing the Git commit id as a constant. We obtain the commit id programmatically using 'GitSharp'. Here is a snippet:

`// Use relative path to .gitignore for the following statement
using (var repo = new Repository(".\\..\\..\\..")) { 
   shortHead = repo.Head.CurrentCommit.ShortHash;
   // shortHead now contains the git commit id
}`

All other projects then reference the file AssemblyInfoShared.cs by link to avoid duplicates. As a result each of these other projects can display the Git commit id where needed including a file _Layout.cshtml, which may display the commit id in the footer.

This solution works for Azure web sites in combination with a custom deploy script for Kudu. It may also work in other scenarios where Kudu is used. It is important that the additional project is built first, so that it also executes the post-build steps. Locally it is sufficient to just build the solution.

We've used this approach in many projects. One example is available at [https://app.storkk.com](https://app.storkk.com/)

Additional notes:

- As of writing GitSharp hasn't received maintenance in a while. However, for now it seems to work just fine.
- You may want to consider to exclude AssemblyInfoShared.cs from versioning as it will be re-generated during each build.
- You may need to set up a dependency manually within your solution to ensure the projects are build in the correct sequence.